# Python 3, MySQL and PyMySQL on a Windows 7 box

Tags: python, mysql, activestate, pymysql

I might be asking the impossible. However, I am trying to connect to MySQL on a windows 7 box using Python 3.3.0. I've using PyMySQL as a way to connect, but this appears not to be supported for a Windows box. I'm not wedded to pymysql, is there a way to achieve this without dropping back to a prior Python version.

Active state doesn't appear to offer a solution for Python 3.X

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than use any other connector. I found that MySQL have a Python 3.3 MySQL connector which solves this issue. You can take a look here and this really solves the issues in a quick way and documentation is really good too. This works on Windows 7 but I have no idea about other platforms.

The latest version of Python MySQL connector.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/myconnpy_example_connecting.html

Good luck.